# Text become unreadable when click submit

Tags: ckeditor

I have a question about CKEditor, when I try to submit it to database, it become unreadable text (use **Khmer unicode**). I have tried to read other forum and I have found some solutions but, it still not work, I don't want to change to use other editor instead.

could anyone tell me.

Original text :

```
អង់គ្លេស៖ យោងតាមប្រភពព័ត៌មាន បានឲ្យដឹងថា ក្លិបបាល់ទាត់ តោខៀវ Chelsea របស់ប្រទេសអង់គ្លេស បានឈានជើង ចូលយ៉ាងជិត ក្នុងការទិញយក កីឡាករបាល់ទាត់ ដ៏ល្បីឈ្មោះ Lionel Messi ខណៈកីឡាករ រូបនេះ បានត្រៀមខ្លួន រួចជាស្រេច ក្នុងការ ចុះកុងត្រា ជាមួយក្លិបបាល់ទាត់ តោខៀវ Chelsea បន្ទាប់ពីឆ្អែតឆ្អន់ និងមិនសប្បាយចិត្ត ជាមួយនឹង ក្លិបបាល់ទាត់ Barcelona របស់ប្រទេសអេស្ប៉ាញ។
```

Result :

```
áž¢áž„áŸ‹áž‚áŸ’áž›áŸážŸáŸ– áž™áŸ„áž„ážáž¶áž˜áž”áŸ’ážšáž—áž–áž–áŸážáŸŒáž˜áž¶áž“ áž”áž¶áž“áž²áŸ’áž™ážŠáž¹áž„ážáž¶ áž€áŸ’áž›áž·áž”áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž‘áž¶ážáŸ‹ ážáŸ„ážáŸ€ážœ Chelsea ážšáž”ážŸáŸ‹áž”áŸ’ážšáž‘áŸážŸáž¢áž„áŸ‹áž‚áŸ’áž›áŸážŸ áž”áž¶áž“ážˆáž¶áž“áž‡áž¾áž„ áž…áž¼áž›áž™áŸ‰áž¶áž„áž‡áž·áž áž€áŸ’áž“áž»áž„áž€áž¶ážšáž‘áž·áž‰áž™áž€ áž€áž¸áž¡áž¶áž€ážšáž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž‘áž¶ážáŸ‹ ážŠáŸáž›áŸ’áž”áž¸ážˆáŸ’áž˜áŸ„áŸ‡ Lionel Messi ážážŽáŸˆáž€áž¸áž¡áž¶áž€ážš ážšáž¼áž”áž“áŸáŸ‡ áž”áž¶áž“ážáŸ’ážšáŸ€áž˜ážáŸ’áž›áž½áž“ ážšáž½áž…áž‡áž¶ážŸáŸ’ážšáŸáž… áž€áŸ’áž“áž»áž„áž€áž¶ážš áž…áž»áŸ‡áž€áž»áž„ážáŸ’ážšáž¶ áž‡áž¶áž˜áž½áž™áž€áŸ’áž›áž·áž”áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž‘áž¶ážáŸ‹ ážáŸ„ážáŸ€ážœ Chelsea áž”áž“áŸ’áž‘áž¶áž”áŸ‹áž–áž¸áž†áŸ’áž¢áŸ‚ážáž†áŸ’áž¢áž“áŸ‹ áž“áž·áž„áž˜áž·áž“ážŸáž”áŸ’áž”áž¶áž™áž…áž·ážáŸ’áž áž‡áž¶áž˜áž½áž™áž“áž¹áž„ áž€áŸ’áž›áž·áž”áž”áž¶áž›áŸ‹áž‘áž¶ážáŸ‹ Barcelona ážšáž”ážŸáŸ‹áž”áŸ’ážšáž‘áŸážŸáž¢áŸážŸáŸ’áž”áŸ‰áž¶áž‰áŸ”
```

Comment: well maybe show us a solution you tried

Comment: this is what I had used : <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: You gave far to little information. What's the language that you're using? Provide a snippet of code that is handling (I suppose) POST data? I don't think it's the editor fault, because CKEditor sample works fine with your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the editor's issue, that's a charset issue during posting data via browser.

You need to add following meta tag in your HTML page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Another remark if your issue related to the database, you need also to set charset for your database (mysql) or also with using the right data type for the field of your database (ex: nvarchar for MS SQL Server etc.).